# Firefox/Chrome empty label content position glitch/bug

Tags: html, css

How to put these red boxes in line? One in the middle jumps down for no reason.

```css
nav label {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <label></label>
  <label>2</label>
  <label></label>
</nav>
```

I need to preserve empty labels empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `vertical-align` and change its *default value* of *baseline*, which is the reason behind the unwanted result, to e.g. `top`:

```css
nav label {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top; /* or "middle", "bottom" */
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <label></label>
  <label>2</label>
  <label></label>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was stunned by this one.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Otherwise this isn't a bug, it's just a default behavior or effect of the baseline, where the nonempty label is aligned with other siblings by the bottom line of its content, which is called the baseline. Or in other words, words lay on it.

Comment: @user619271 another magic trick is to add `overflow: auto;` to the middle element which will make the baseline be the bottom (like the others) and no need to adjust vertical-align

Comment: You got that right @TemaniAfif